# Nikon D800E focus problem with YN685N and yn622n-tx in low light situations

Tags: nikon, flash, autofocus, low-light

I'm using a Nikon D800E with my 24-70 f/2.8 lens. The problem happens in low-light situations using a YN-685N and YN-622N-TX. I shoot at f/5.6 and pics aren't that sharp, but when I use my SB-910 it's all good even on f/2.8. The situation is a little better at f/8 but it's too much for me. I am using YN's AF-assist red grid and I always get focus confirmation. Anyone had a similar issue?

Comment: Related: [YN685 AF assist not aligned with focus points — can anything be done?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/72379/yn685-af-assist-not-aligned-with-focus-points-can-anything-be-done/77500#77500)

Answer (score 1):

This is probably motion blur, your shutter speed is too long. Try opening it to F2.8. It is very strange that it gets better at F8 though, could it be a lucky shot?